# ¿Es correcto decir "trolear" en castellano?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, coloquialismos, jerga-internet

Estaba leyendo la entrevista [David Fernández: “Aprecio de España más cosas de las que combato. El adversario es el Estado”](https://www.elsaltodiario.com/cup/aprecio-de-espana-mas-cosas-de-las-que-combato-el-adversario-es-el-estado#) cuando me encontré con este fragmento:

> No hay que perder el sentido del humor ni en los momentos más grises, si a mí me dicen hace años que un president iba a **trolear** al Gobierno del Estado por Twitter, no me lo creería, lo digo con respecto a lo de la página web.

A lo que se refiere esta persona es a que el presidente del Gobierno de Cataluña (*president*, en catalán) [explicó en Twitter](https://twitter.com/krls/status/908027118264647682) cómo esquivar la prohibición del gobierno de España de acceder a una página web (indicó otra con el mismo contenido).

El uso de *trolear* parece venir de la palabra:

> [**trol**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=alNfPu5)
>   Del noruego *troll* 'ser sobrenatural'.
>   1. m. En la mitología escandinava, monstruo maligno que habita en bosques o grutas.

pero en el ámbito de internet y en inglés parece que ha ido creciendo su uso, cogiendo bastantes significados: molestar (ser un troll en un foro es reventarlo), insultar... o vacilar, como sería este caso. Por no hablar de cuando se dice que alguien *es un trol* para decir que es feo.

Me doy cuenta de hecho que hay otras noticias con los mismos protagonistas en que la palabra *trolear* está presente, por ejemplo [Puigdemont *trolea* a Rajoy](http://www.elperiodico.com/es/politica/20161020/carles-puigdemont-trolea-mariano-rajoy-5577016), por lo que esta palabra, que parecería puro coloquialismo, está tomando peso.

Me pregunto entonces: ¿es correcto usar *trolear* en castellano? Si no lo es, ¿qué otras palabras castizas podríamos utilizar para decir lo mismo? ¿Se usa en Hispanoamérica?

Comment: Hay varias preguntas de este tipo en el sitio, y tras un tiempo al final creo haber llegado a la conclusión de que la respuesta es siempre la misma: las palabras significan lo que nosotros queramos. Si queremos que "trolear" signifique "vacilar", "insultar" o "molestar", pues así será, y la RAE como notaria tendrá que atestiguarlo. Tal vez este tipo de preguntas deba reformularse como "¿Existe una alternativa más castiza para 'trolear'?" en vez de preguntarse si su uso es correcto.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Desde la versión 23.4 del DLE ([publicada en noviembre de 2020](https://www.rae.es/noticia/la-actualizacion-234-del-diccionario-de-la-lengua-espanola-incorporara-2557-novedades-en-su)), esta acepción ya aparece:

> [**trolear**](https://dle.rae.es/trolear)
> `Del ingl. to troll y -ear.`
>
> 1. tr. En foros de internet y redes sociales, publicar mensajes provocativos, ofensivos o fuera de lugar con el fin de boicotear algo o a alguien, o entorpecer la conversación. U. t. c. intr.

---

Hay que recordar siempre que la RAE no es juez, sino notaria del lenguaje, y que las palabras tienen el significado que nosotros queramos darle. Tú mismo propones que "trolear" significa "vacilar", pero ¿qué significa "vacilar"?

Según el NTLLE, en el siglo XVIII tenía tres significados: "moverse indeterminadamente", "dudar, titubear" y "estar poco firme alguna cosa". Más de 200 años más tarde, en 1992 significaba lo mismo. Seguía sin tener esa acepción de "engañar, burlarse de alguien". Y un buen día la gente decidió que se le podía dar ese significado, empezó a usarla así, y en 2001 la palabra "vacilar" se encontró con una nueva acepción:

> **[vacilar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bEjxKUN)**
>
> Del lat. *vacillāre*.
>
> 5. tr. Engañar, tomar el pelo, burlarse o reírse de alguien.

Y ciertamente, no he encontrado en el CORDE ningún caso de "vacilar" con este sentido, y solo uno en el CREA (registrado como "oral", de 1996: *"Sí, anda, iros a vacilar a vuestro puñetero padre, anda."*). ¿Se consideraría que "vacilar" es una palabra *castiza* del español, válida para sustituir a "trolear"? Igual sí, pero no hay que perder de vista que esa acepción hasta hace nada era un neologismo.

En todo caso, por responder a tu pregunta, creo que las palabras que propones son acertadas ("molestar", "insultar" y "vacilar"), aunque en la definición de "vacilar" encontramos expresiones aún más tradicionales: "burlarse", "reírse de alguien", o incluso "tomar el pelo". El titular, pues, podría haber sido:

> Puigdemont **le toma el pelo** a Rajoy.

Y tal vez habría tenido más corrección lingüística. En todo caso hay que tener en cuenta que los periódicos son un buen medio para la expansión de estos neologismos, y que además necesitan conectar con la gente joven para poder seguir teniendo lectores, luego tienen que adaptarse a los cambios en las formas de expresarse.

[He preguntado a la RAE](https://twitter.com/charliealejo/status/910449952626761728) si están estudiando añadir al DLE "trolear" con el significado de "burlarse, tomar el pelo". El caso es que alguien preguntó ya algo parecido pero con el significado de "hostigar" (más propio de los troles de Internet), y [la RAE respondió](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/887664911345700864):

> «Troleo» y «trolear» no figuran aún en el DLE, pero son derivados correctos de «trol».

Nótese el uso de "aún", que puede indicar que igual ya se lo están pensando. [La respuesta que me han dado](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/910479743459495936) a mí es similar:

> No está aún en el DLE, pero se usa como 'intervenir en las redes sociales para estorbar y molestar'.

No me cuadra mucho con los usos que se le dan hoy día, llegando al ámbito del mundo real (fuera de las redes sociales), y con un significado que vira más bien hacia "burlarse", "quedarse con alguien", "dar una lección a alguien", como [en este titular](http://www.antena3.com/noticias/deportes/virales/troleo-definitivo-padre-hijo-recorre-estados-unidos-diciendole-hijo-que-estudie_2017032858da802f0cf2f510fd860e13.html):

> El 'troleo' definitivo de un padre a su hijo: recorre los pabellones de la NBA diciéndole que estudie

Así que [respondí a la RAE](https://twitter.com/charliealejo/status/910486923394912256), indagando un poco más sobre este tema, y [me admitieron que](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/910488769341607936):

> El argot de las redes sociales está, en general, extendiéndose fuera de esos límites, con usos más o menos fig[urados].

Y posteriormente me animaron a remitir a la RAE mis sugerencias al diccionario.

En cuanto a la última pregunta, no sé si se usa en Hispanoamérica con este significado, pero comentar que la palabra existe con otro:

> **[trolear](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=trolear)**
>
> 1. tr. Ho. En el ejército, castigar a alguien con ejercicios
>    físicos extenuantes.
> 2. intr. CR. Realizar un paseo o recorrido largo a pie. pop + cult → espon.
> 3. tr. Ho. En los deportes, derrotar con contundencia al oponente.

Y en el CORDE me aparece una frase en un texto mexicano:

> *Se trata de un viejo camaronero de esas flotas pesqueras que proceden del Norte. Y el cual mientras troleaba pesadamente en los bajos de una barra cercana, empezó a sentir que las carenas se le agrietaban con el esfuerzo y se puso a hacer agua desde la tajamar al codaste, por toda la sentina.*
>
> Ramón Rubín, "Los Rezagados", 1991 (México).

No estoy seguro de cuál es el significado en esta frase, aunque tras ponerme @mdewey en la pista veo que se refiere a una técnica de pesca de arrastre llamada "[pesca al curricán](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pesca_al_curric%C3%A1n)", "pesca a la cacea"​ o "trolling", dado que el sujeto de la frase es un barco que está realizando esta actividad.

Por su parte, [la Fundeu tiene su propio artículo](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/trolear-troleo/) sobre la palabra *trolear*, de la cual de partida dice que es correcta escrita así, con una *l*. En el artículo se expone lo siguiente:

> El sustantivo *trol* [...] ha dado lugar
> a las formas derivadas *trolear* y *troleo*, empleadas en un principio en
> internet para referirse a la acción y al efecto de intervenir en un
> foro digital con el objetivo de generar polémica, ofender y provocar
> de modo malintencionado a los demás usuarios [...].
>
> A partir de este primer uso, estas voces han ido extendiendo su
> significado, de modo que se aplican a múltiples contextos, no siempre
> digitales, con la idea sobre todo de ‘intervenir con ánimo de hacer
> fracasar algo’. Con este sentido, *trolear* puede alternar con otros
> verbos como *reventar*, *boicotear*, *provocar*...
>
> También se documentan usos con significados próximos como ‘molestar,
> cansar o enfadar’ y, especialmente, ‘tomar el pelo, vacilar o gastar
> una broma, por lo general pesada’.

Así que, efectivamente, confirma su expansión hacia el mundo real (fuera de internet) y su cambio de significado. Posteriormente, recuerda (como ya hemos visto) que *trolear* tiene significados diferentes en Hispanoamérica.

---

**Resumiendo:**

- ¿Es correcta? Sí. Siempre que tu mensaje se entienda por tus lectores, es correcta. Que esté o no en el DLE es irrelevante: si no lo está lo estará con el tiempo si se sigue usando. El lenguaje lo creamos nosotros.
- ¿Alternativas? Según el sentido que le quieras dar: *vacilar, burlarse, tomar el pelo, molestar*...
- ¿Se usa en Hispanoamérica? Sí, pero no con el mismo sentido que en España.

Comment: Pues ya tenemos la palabra en el DLE :confeti: :D